# Read one number per line from file Java

Tags: java, file, input, stream

So I have a file that I have two numbers per line which represent coordinates. How can I read the two numbers each time and put them into int variables x,y ignoring the white spaces from line to line?

The file looks like that: (Note that every pair is at a different line)

```
8 23
130 28
23 108
50 99
108 107
52 54
115 107
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anythind because that is my question. Is there any way in java that I can read from a file the first two ints and put them in x and y and then read the next two from the next line .

Comment: Have you tried with simple split? Such as `String[] lines = text.split('\n');` to get the array containing all the lines and then a loop `for(String line : lines)` foreach line. Inside the loop `String[] coordinates = line.split(' ');`. Something like this maybe...

Comment: Well then you should approach the problem in smaller parts: 1. Find out how to read text from a file. 2. Learn how to split strings by a space. 3. Finally learn how to convert a `String` to an `int`.

Comment: With text being the content? Of the file? Also note (I haven't mentioned it I'm sorry) that I cannot (for my project's sake) use Files.readString(Paths.get(filename)). So is there any other way to take the file content?

Comment: @Vins did the second part I described for you. Now I went on google and found the following solution for the first one. The final part can be taken from Ralf Wagener's answer. https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/09/how-to-read-file-into-string-in-java-7.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how to read the coordinates from a file called `input.txt` and parse them into integer variables `x` and `y`:

```
    Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("input.txt"));
    lines.forEach(
            line -> {
                String[] split = line.split(" ");

                int x = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
                int y = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);

                System.out.println("x = " + x);
                System.out.println("y = " + y);
            }
    );
```

Or without using `Files.lines()`:

```
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {

        String[] split = line.split(" ");

        int x = Integer.parseInt(split[0]);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(split[1]);

        System.out.println("x = " + x);
        System.out.println("y = " + y);

        // read next line
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    reader.close();
```

Comment: That would work perfectly but unfortunately I am not allowed to use the Path.

Comment: Any other things you're not allowed to use?

Comment: No. just the Path. That's why I have a problem with reading the content. Otherwise I would use this Files.lines(Paths.get("input.txt"));

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Scanner` but you need double `while` loop

```
    FileReader fin = new FileReader("Test.txt");

    Scanner src = new Scanner(fin);
    while (src.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = src.nextLine();
        Scanner src2 = new Scanner(line);
        while(src2.hasNext()) {
            int n = src2.nextInt();
            System.out.print(n  + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

You can also use `StreamTokenizer`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help I'll keep this in mind.